# Adding values from one list to another when they share value

Tags: python

I'm trying to add values from List2 if the type is the same in List1. All the data is strings within lists. This isn't the exact data I'm using, just a representation. This is my first programme so please excuse any misunderstandings.

```py
List1 = [['Type A =', 'Value 1', 'Value 2', 'Value 3'], ['Type B =', 'Value 4', 'Value 5']]
List2 = [['Type Z =', 'Value 6', 'Value 7', 'Value 8'], ['Type A =', 'Value 9', 'Value 10', 'Value 11'], ['Type A =', 'Value 12', 'Value 13']]
```

Desired result:

```py
new_list =[['Type A =', 'Value 1', 'Value 2', 'Value 3', 'Value 9', 'Value 10', 'Value 11', 'Value 12', 'Value 13'], ['Type B =', 'Value 4', 'Value 5']]
```

Current attempt:

```py
newlist = []
for values in List1:
    for valuestoadd in List2:
        if values[0] == valuestoadd[0]:
            newlist = [List1 + [valuestoadd[1:]]]
        else:
            print("Types don't match")
    return newlist
```

This works for me if there weren't two Type A's in List2 as this causes my code to create two instances of List1. If I was able to add the values at a specific index of the list then that would be great but I can work around that.

Comment: `newlist = [List1 + [valuestoadd[1:]]` is missing a bracket?

Comment: Might be easier to do with a dictionary.

Comment: Well, your base of `newlist` is always `List1`, unless the types never match. In that case `newlist =  []`. So your problem is that if `List2` has more than 1 list with type A, you don't get the result appended. So why don't you just do `newlist = List1`. After that if there is a match: `newlist.append(valuestoadd[1:]`. And if you never appended anything you can simply do `newlist = []` in the end. So this suggestion behaves the same as your code and doesn't ignore multiple entries of the same type.

Comment: @PaulErlenmeyer doing that doesn't work, as it appends to the end of the big list, rather than the `type A` list. if you observe my answer below, i've laid out what would be required to stick with only lists, ignoring dictionaries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's probably easier to use a dictionary for this:

```
def merge(d1, d2):
    return {k: v + d2[k] if k in d2 else v for k, v in d1.items()}

d1 = {'A': [1, 2, 3], 'B': [4, 5, 6]}
d2 = {'A': [7, 8, 9], 'C': [0]}
print(merge(d1, d2))
```

If you *must* use a list, it's fairly easy to temporarily convert to a dictionary and back to a list:

```
from collections import defaultdict

def list_to_dict(xss):
    d = defaultdict(list)
    for xs in xss:
        d[xs[0]].extend(xs[1:])
    return d

def dict_to_list(d):
    return [[k, *v] for k, v in d.items()]
```

Comment: This is clean and pythonic, but here is the output `{'A': [7, 8, 9, 1, 2, 3]}`, I think he wants `B` and `C` too.

Comment: @Mustapha-Belkacim Thanks, I've now included the 'B', though it doesn't look like he wants 'C' in the example provided.

Comment: from his question, I think you're right, but it doesn't make sense

Comment: Thank you. If List2 also had Type B values that I needed to add to the Type B section of List1, would this method work? I think this will work on my code if so.

Comment: @Dean1886 Yep. Since it looks like you also have duplicate keys within each list, I modified `list_to_dict` to account for that.

Comment: Thank you. I'll take a look at using this.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than using `List1 + [valuestoadd[1:]]`, you should be using `newlist[0].append(valuestoadd[1:])` so that it doesn't ever create a new list and only appends to the old one. The `[0]` is necessary so that it appends to the first sublist rather than the whole list.

```py
newlist = List1 #you're doing this already - might as well initialize the new list with this code
for values in List1:
    for valuestoadd in List2:
        if values[0] == valuestoadd[0]:
            newlist[0].append(valuestoadd[1:]) #adds the values on to the end of the first list
        else:
            print("Types don't match")

Output:
[['Type A =', 'Value 1', 'Value 2', 'Value 3', ['Value 9', 'Value 10', 'Value 11'], ['Value 12', 'Value 13']], ['Type B =', 'Value 4', 'Value 5']]
```

This does, sadly, input the values as a list - if you want to split them into individual values, you would need to iterate through the lists you're adding on, and append individual values to `newlist[0]`.

This could be achieved with another `for` loop, like so:

```py
if values[0] == valuestoadd[0]:
    for subvalues in valuestoadd[1:]: #splits the list into subvalues
        newlist[0].append(subvalues) #appends those subvalues

Output:
[['Type A =', 'Value 1', 'Value 2', 'Value 3', 'Value 9', 'Value 10', 'Value 11', 'Value 12', 'Value 13'], ['Type B =', 'Value 4', 'Value 5']]
```

Comment: Thank you for the response. 

If List2 also had Type B values that I needed to add to the Type B section of List1, would this method work? I've tried running it but can only get it to add the Type B values to the Type A section of List1.

Comment: You'd have to change it to `newlist[1]` because that's where Type B is, so it's likely a dictionary would be much better.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with the other answers that it would be better to use a dictionary right away. But if you want, for some reason, stick to the data structure you have, you could transform it into a dictionary and back:

```
type_dict = {}
for tlist in List1+List2:
    curr_type = tlist[0]
    type_dict[curr_type] = tlist[1:] if not curr_type in type_dict else type_dict[curr_type]+tlist[1:]
new_list = [[k] + type_dict[k] for k in type_dict]
```

In the creation of new_list, you can take the keys from a subset of type_dict only if you do not want to include all of them.

Comment: Thank you. Think I need to take a further look at dictionaries as I've only really used lists until now.